# AlamoFire: How to access an API that is protected with Cloudflare DDoS protection?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm new to Swift and iOS app development. Currently I'm creating a pokémon app. For this I used to talk to the pokeapi.co API with alamofire:

```
let url = NSURL("http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/55/")!
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in
  let result = response.result
  /* handle result */
}
```

Since a couple of hours (I guess) pokeapi.co is protected with cloudflare thus preventing my code from accessing the API.
When I test the GET request (with postman) I get a response from the page that says:

> "Checking your browser before accessing pokeapi.co. This process is
>   automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content
>   shortly. Please allow up to 5 seconds"

I don't get past this in my code so my app never receives the requested data.

How can I talk to an API with Alamofire, protected with DDoS protection by Cloudflare?

Comment: If cloudflare has blocked you specifically, it's likely via the IP address. So this will change (you can try a few things to get a new ip). If they have identified your app as a potential threat and blocked it, then there isn't a great deal you can do. You would likely have to contact Cloudflare or log a support ticket for the API. Also, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not Cloudflare or Pokemon Support. see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: They didn't block me, but when I do the GET request with postman, I get the page that says: _"Checking your browser before accessing pokeapi.co. This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly. Please allow up to 5 seconds"_ I don't get past this so my app never receives the requested data.

Comment: Cloudflare makes this prompt when it thinks the request is coming from something that is a threat, or maybe even just automated and making alot of requests. It wont redirect, like you say, it runs some checks on the browser user-agent and other things to determine if your a human or not. I dont think there is a way around it, or at least, not an easy one